# Progressive Web App can't be installed in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, json, progressive-web-apps

I build an unit converter in html and javascript. My last Problem is to make the app installable. But the button in chrome dont appear. But the Service Worker is running as I can see it in chrom dev tools. I am using Ubuntu 18.04,the VS Code extension Live Server and an up to date chrome browser. I also tried Firefox and my smartphone. Both dont work too.

Here my serviceworker.js:

```
const cacheName = 'Einheitenrechner';
const staticAssets = [
    '/',
    '/index.html',
    '/scripts/app.js',
    '/style/app.css',
    '/manifest.json'
];

self.addEventListener('install',function(event){
    event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName)
      .then(function(cache) {
        console.log('Opened cache');
        return cache.addAll(staticAssets);
      })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate',function(event){
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then((keyList) => {
          return Promise.all(keyList.map((key) => {
            if (key !== cacheName) {
              console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing old cache', key);
              return caches.delete(key);
            }
          }));
        })
    );;
    self.clients.claim();
});



self.addEventListener('fetch', async e =>{
    // CODELAB: Add fetch event handler here.
    if (evt.request.mode !== 'navigate') {
    // Not a page navigation, bail.
        return;
    }
    evt.respondWith(
      fetch(evt.request)
          .catch(() => {
            return caches.open(cacheName)
                .then((cache) => {
                  return cache.match('index.html');
                });
          })
  );
});
```

my register-sw.js:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('scripts/serviceworker.js')
          .then((reg) => {
            console.log('Service worker registered.', reg);
          });
    });
  }
```

Comment: As Ian mentions below, you need to run the lighthouse tools using your HTTPS URL. Most likely that will tell you that you have issues to fix before your code is considered an installable PWA.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information here for a proper answer. I suggest you use the Chrome tools to check it. In "Audits" there is a Progressive Web App check (also know as [Lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/)). If you run this it should tell you if there are any problems with your app. If you can edit your question with the results one of us may be able to provide a better answer.